# Pip package (pendulum 2.1) fails to install with FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, filenotfoundexception, pendulum

During the installation process of pendulum I get a FileNotFoundError exception.

I ran it multiple times and all of them failed. It did work for `pendulum==2.1.1`.

```
Collecting pendulum==2.1.2 (from -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-main/constraints-3.6.txt (line 354))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/15/6e89ae7cde7907118769ed3d2481566d05b5fd362724025198bb95faf599/pendulum-2.1.2.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/jorricks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/7s/k78t7hcx6g75x9jg8wmj13z40000gn/T/pip-install-xuv35z0w/pendulum/setup.py'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/7s/k78t7hcx6g75x9jg8wmj13z40000gn/T/pip-install-xuv35z0w/pendulum/
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
~/Projects/airflow ~/Projects/airflow
#######################################################################
  You had some troubles installing the venv !!!!!
  Try running the command below and rerun virtualenv installation

  brew install sqlite mysql postgresql openssl
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

#######################################################################

ERROR: The previous step completed with error. Please take a look at output above
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was due to the pip version I used to install it with.

Simply by updating pip with `pip install --upgrade pip` it started working again.